# Words to differentiate between Class and Wealth

Tags: word-choice, class-based-usage

While there are many answers differentiating between class in a moral sense, (e.g. "Look at Johnny, cavorting with clowns. He truly has no class.") and wealth (see [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/314747/word-to-describe-person-who-is-rich-in-wealth-but-is-poor-in-class), I can't find any between class with regards to social standing and wealth, for instance:

What would be a word for each of the following:
1. A person without social standing with a great deal of wealth (but isn't necessarily newly wealthy,for instance some of the rich plebeian families of the late Republic)?

2. A person with great social standing but without much wealth (much like the Julian Caesars (or is it Caesarian Julians?) during/immediately after Sulla's civil wars, so not nouveau riche as some suggested in the aforementioned question, as they are such an old family, nor even vulgarian, as it is a different kind of class)?

Comment: For 1: a "rich bumpkin". For 2: a "penniless aristocrat".

Comment: 1. (I think) The red coats use "toff".  Well mate, do I have it right?

Comment: Sorry for the lateness, but I'd love to accept @Graffito's answer if you'd write it up in an answer form!